# how to get jbpm DB version?

Tags: jbpm

I can get JBPM version from db version as follows:

```
JbpmVersion.getJbpmVersion("dbversion");
```

But how to get the DB version itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 org.jbpm.pvm.internal.id.PropertyImpl.getDbVersion(session);

 String dbVersion = PropertyImpl.getDbVersion(session);
```

See the link here

[org.jbpm.pvm.internal.id.PropertyImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jbpm.jbpm4/jbpm-pvm/4.3/org/jbpm/pvm/internal/id/PropertyImpl.java#PropertyImpl.getDbVersion%28org.hibernate.Session%29)